# The "ExpressionTranslationBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a Visual Studio sharepoint 2013 workflow, and I'm getting this error:

```
The "ExpressionTranslationBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Activities.Debugger.XamlDebuggerXmlReader.InjectLineInfoMembersToBuffer(DocumentLocation startPosition, DocumentLocation endPosition)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.XamlDebuggerXmlReader.InjectLineInfoXamlNodesToBuffer()
   at System.Activities.Debugger.XamlDebuggerXmlReader.Read()
   at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.DynamicActivityXamlReader.Read()
   at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
   at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Load(XamlReader xamlReader)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Design.ExpressionTranslation.ExpressionTranslator.GetRootObject(XamlReader reader, Boolean useInvariantCulture)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Design.ExpressionTranslation.ExpressionTranslator.TryGetActivitySourceInfoAndExpressionLanguage(XamlReader inputXamlReader, Object& rootObject, Activity& rootActivity, String& expressionLanguage, Dictionary`2& activitySourceInformation, List`1& translationErrors)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Design.ExpressionTranslation.ExpressionTranslator.TranslateInternal(XamlReader inputXamlReader, String localAssemblyPath, String compiledExpressionRootTypeName)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Design.ExpressionTranslation.ExpressionTranslator.Translate(TextReader textReader, XamlSchemaContext schemaContext, String localAssemblyPath, String compiledExpressionRootTypeName)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Service.Build.ExpressionTranslationBuildTask.TryTranslate(String xamlFile, String typeName, XamlSchemaContext schemaContext, String translatedXamlFile)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Service.Build.ExpressionTranslationBuildTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() Structure
```

Is this an actual error in the compiler translating the xaml into activities?
There's no line/column number highlighting where the problem is.
I can replicate this consistently. Google found [TWO results](https://www.google.com/search?q=expressiontranslationbuildtask%20failed%20unexpectedly), neither of which are relevant.

By the way, this is the second time this happened. The first time, I started doing the workflow from scratch. Where do I start? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out to be (Code activity) assembly related. The Visual Studio designer was generating corrupt XAML with bad namespaces scattered in-line everywhere. What's interesting is that it eventually generates .g.cs files from the XAML and places them in the \debug\obj directory. It was then finding compile-time ERRORS in the files generated by itself!

After going through all of the namespaces and essentially redoing the workflow, the issue was fixed.